# What's the correct way to do ajax callback with Rails 3 link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Here's the scenario.

**Summary:**
I have a solution, but I want to know if this is the best way to get an AJAX callback working in Rails 3.

**Problem:**
I have a link that when clicked it should use AJAX to update an existing html element (in my case a `div`) on the page:

`<div id="project_content">Change Goes here</div>`

**My Solution**
In my `projects/show.html.erb`

> true} %>

My TasksController is as follows:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        respond_to do |format|
              format.html
              format.js { render action: "index", script: true }
        end
    end
end
```

and in my `tasks/index.js.erb` I have

> $("#project_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'tasks')%>");

**Question:**
This all works. But WHY do I have to do all of this? Wasn't there (or isn't there) a solution that used to all us to simply do this

`<%= link_to "tasks",  project_tasks_path(@project), {:remote=>true, :update=>"project_content"} %>`

And this would then load `tasks/index.js.erb` into whichever element the key `:update` references?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to reinvent [link_to_remote](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote) from old Rails 2.3. Such a solution in general comes out to be too complex and rigid.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: @haroldcampbell Spend some time examing `link_to_remote` functionality. It even has the `:update` option which you propose.

Comment: But `link_to_remote` was removed from Rails 3+: With that said the questions remains. What's the replacement for `link_to_remote` where I can simply supply an `:update` hash?

Comment: @haroldcampbell Your question was "WHY do I have to do all of this?". And the answer is because [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is the right way to do things. That's why `link_to_remote` is gone in Rails 3.