# Rails - trying to create simple ajax example

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

The code below is not working for some reason. As I click at "test" it redirects me to /home/test and shows nothing.

**view/home/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "test", { :controller => "home", :action => "test" }, :remote => true %>
   <div id='test_div'>
</div>
```

**view/home/index.js.erb**

```
$("#test_div").html("some text");
```

**controller**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def test
    "test123 test456"
    respond_to() do |format|
      format.js {render :layout => false}
    end
  end
end
```

What should I do to refresh div_test using ajax?

Comment: use the console to see if your link_to remote works, and use console.log to get the responses, I think you need change $ to jQuery('#test_div').html("some test");

Comment: There's nothing useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your routes file look like? Can you post it on here? Do a rake routes and post the output.

Here are some things that may help you:

1. [Rails documentation for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
2. Also, check out the [Ajax on Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) and the section on link_to_remote. The `link_to_remote` function is not in Rails. What version of rails are you on? Bash: `$ rails -v`
3. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766383/rails-3-link-to-to-call-partial-using-jquery-ajax) on S.O. regarding AJAX on Rails calls.
4. Edit: Here is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496172/how-to-use-link-to-with-ajax-in-rails-3-2-1) answer regarding this that may help.
5. [Another answer on SO for updating existing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655142/whats-the-correct-way-to-do-ajax-callback-with-rails-3-link-to)

Edit: looking over this again, I dont think you need `()` after `respond_to` or the `{...}` in `link_to`. Look at the third link. I think you need to put the page in a partial and render it. Its not rendering right now since its `render :layout => false`

Comment: I count more than two, but +2 for more!

Comment: Well... I'm almost 5 years late, but I fixed the "2" haha!